# Convergence distribution of $\sqrt{n} (X - 1) $ when $X \sim InvGamma(n, 1/n)$

Tags: probability, asymptotics

I'm figuring out the asymptotic distribution $\sqrt{n} (X_n - 1) $ when $X_n \sim \mathrm{InvGamma}(n, 1/n)$, where $1/n$ is a shape parameter.

I **tried**:

$ \frac{1}{X_n} \overset{d}{=} Z_1 + \cdots + Z_n$, where $Z_i \overset{iid}{\sim}\mathrm{Gamma}(1, 1/n)$

$\mathbb{E} (X_n) = \frac{n}{n-1}$, $var(X_n) = \frac{n^2}{(n-1)^2(n-2)}$.

But I can't proceed further. Can anybody give some hints?

Comment: $1/X$ has a Gamma$(n,1/n)$ distribution.  What happens to it asymptotically?  You can work it out directly or apply the Central Limit Theorem.

Comment: Are you sure you need an asymptotic distribution? The expression $\sqrt{n}(X-1)$ is just a scaled and shifted inverse Gamma variable; its asymptotic distribution is just its exact distribution which is easily recoverable.